# NSPredicate to filter the relationship

Tags: ios, core-data, nspredicate

Let's assume I have Person and Pet entities, and one-to-many relationship, so Person have a pet list. At the moment I can filter by pet's age using this predicate (in both Swift and Objective-C for your convenience)

```
NSPredicate(format: "pets.age > 3")
[NSPedicate predicateWithFormat:@"pets.age > 3"]
```

but this is rather uncomfortable and not very robust – as Pet entity might be queried from many other entities (i.e. doctor, from other pet siblings, maybe pet toys, etc – just for your imagination).

What I would like to do:

```
NSPredicate(format: "pets MATCH %@", NSPredicate(format: "age > 3"))
[NSPedicate predicateWithFormat:@"pets MATCH %@", [NSPedicate predicateWithFormat:@"age > 3"]]
```

so I can Pet entity to give me correct predicate for age, and then use it in any other predicates. How can I archive that? I would like to use it on CoreData on iOS device, so it's rather important which SQL query CoreData will get out of it, because performance matters.

Comment: Not sure I got correctly what do you want to get but seems like subqueries is what you need. Take a look here for example https://www.objc.io/issues/4-core-data/core-data-fetch-requests/#subqueries

Answer (score 2):

You can use `%K` as a key path placeholder in your predicate string

```
NSPredicate(format: "%K > %@", "age", "3")
```

So depending on what you need you could have a few constants with different operators to use when creating your predicates

```
let greaterThanPredicate = "%K > %@"
let equalPredicate = "%K = %@"
```

and so on or some kind of factory class if your requirements are more complex.

Comment: I got your idea. Unfortunately, inner predicate isn't the only one, and it's quite uncomfortable to collect it on the outer side. Factory class is ok, I also found PrediKit pod, but it's quite cumbersome, thus just not worth the time spent.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I got correctly what do you want to get but seems like subqueries is what you need. Take a look [here](https://www.objc.io/issues/4-core-data/core-data-fetch-requests/#subqueries) for example